# Mongodb Map-Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

The data in collection looks like following:

```
[{
  _id: 0001,
  imei:'123456',
  apps:[{packageName:'google'},{packageName:'twitter'}]

},{
  _id: 0002,
  imei:'654321',
  apps:[{packageName:'facebook'},{packageName:'twitter'}
  }]
```

i would like to calculate the packageName and the user's imei, just like this:

```
[{
   packageName:'facebook',
   imeis:['123456']     
 },{
   packageName:'google',
   imeis:['123456','654321']
 },{
   packageName:'twitter',
   imeis:['123456','654321']

 }]
```

my map function is :

```
function(){
  emit(this.packageName,this.imei);
};
```

reduce function is :

```
function(key , values){
  var ret = {packageName:key,imeis:values};
  return ret;
};
```

But the result only have packageName ,imeis is null

maybe the map function was wrong ,but I don't know how to rewrite it.

i'm the new to mongoDB .please give me  some advice ,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better be done with the aggregation framework.

If your collection name is `coll`:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$apps"}, 
    {$group:{
        "_id" : "$apps.packageName",
        "imeis" : { $addToSet: "$imei" }
    }}
],{allowDiskUse: true}
)
```

The [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) aggregation flattens the `apps` array.

The [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation group documents by `packageName`. The [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator group all `imei` unique values into array.

[allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-external-sort) allows you to use temporary files for aggregation pipeline stages if memory usage exceeds limit (100 GB RAM). Alternatively you can use [match](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) as a criteria filter.

Comment: thank u very much ，it can work ,but if  i scan all collection ,mongo show me the msg : 'exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in'.